# how do i insert data from source to two or more tables at the same time in mysql... are there any ways to insert

Tags: mysql, datatable, mysql-workbench

I have three tables, (Table1, Table2 and DataTable) and I want to insert into Table1 and Table2 using DataTable as source. So for every row in DataTable I want a row in Table1 and Table2.how can i do this in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (field1, field2, ...)
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, ... FROM DataTable

INSERT INTO Table2 (field1, field2, ...)
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, ... FROM DataTable
```

With that you insert rows from DataTable into Table1 and Table2. Just to make sure that fields match from the insert and the select statement.

Comment: thanks for ur answer...i think i was not clear wi the question. i have customer table(id, name ,address,.....) and customer account table (acntid,name,address.....) and Datasource table has (name adresss,email,zipcode etc).now i want to insert name and address from data source to customer and customeraccount table at the same time.should we have to write scripts or procedures or triggers or anything elase